# Is it guaranteed that new Integer(i) == i in Java?

Tags: java, comparison, autoboxing, implicit-conversion

Consider the following snippet:

```
    int i = 99999999;
    byte b = 99;
    short s = 9999;
    Integer ii = Integer.valueOf(9); // should be within cache

    System.out.println(new Integer(i) == i); // "true"
    System.out.println(new Integer(b) == b); // "true"
    System.out.println(new Integer(s) == s); // "true"
    System.out.println(new Integer(ii) == ii); // "false"
```

It's obvious why the last line will **ALWAYS** prints `"false"`: we're using `==` reference identity comparison, and a `new` object will **NEVER** be `==` to an already existing object.

The question is about the first 3 lines: are those comparisons ***guaranteed*** to be on the primitive `int`, with the `Integer` auto-unboxed? Are there cases where the primitive would be auto-boxed instead, and reference identity comparisons are performed? (which would all then be `false`!)

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question - all 4 comparisons use ==, which will return false, since you are creating a new instance on the left side of the comparison.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Great question!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  [JLS §5.6.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6.2) specifies the rules for binary numeric promotion.  In part:

> When an operator applies binary
> numeric promotion to a pair of
> operands, each of which must denote a
> value that is convertible to a numeric
> type, the following rules apply, in
> order, using widening conversion
> (§5.1.2) to convert operands as
> necessary:
>
> If any of the operands is of a
> reference type, unboxing conversion
> (§5.1.8) is performed.

Binary numeric promotion applies for several numeric operators, including "the numerical equality operators == and !=."

[JLS §15.21.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.1) (Numerical Equality Operators == and !=) specifies:

> If the operands of an equality
> operator are both of numeric type, or
> one is of numeric type and the other
> is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric
> type, binary numeric promotion is
> performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

In contrast, [JLS §15.21.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.3) (Reference Equality Operators == and !=) provides:

> If the operands of an equality
> operator are both of either reference
> type or the null type, then the
> operation is object equality

This fits the common understanding of boxing and unboxing, that's it only done when there's a mismatch.

Comment: That makes it sound like `new Integer(0) == new Integer(0)` (which is `false`) should be `true`, because "any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion is performed". Can you clarify this further?

Comment: It applies to arithmetic operators, in new Integer(0)==new Integer(0), '==' is reference equality operator, not an arithmetic operator.

Comment: @polygene, I explained further why your comment example uses object equality.

Answer (score 9):

I will first explain *precisely when* `==` is a reference equality, and *precisely when* it's a numerical equality. The conditions for reference equality is simpler, so it will be explained first.

#### [JLS 15.21.3 Reference Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.3)

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the *null* type, then the operation is object equality.

This explains the following:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(0) == new Integer(0)); // "false"
```

Both operands are `Integer`, which are reference types, and that's why the `==` is reference equality comparison, and two `new` objects will never be `==` to each other, so that's why it prints `false`.

For `==` to be numerical equality, *at least one of the operand must be a numeric type*; this is specified as follows:

#### [JLS 15.21.1 Numerical Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.1)

> If the operands of an equality operator are **both** of numeric type, or **one is** of numeric type and **the other is convertible** to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands. If the promoted type of the operands is `int` or `long`, then an integer equality test is performed; if the promoted type is `float or` double`, then a floating-point equality test is performed.
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion and unboxing conversion.

Thus, consider the following:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(0) == 0); // "true"
```

This prints `true`, because:

- the right operand **is** a numeric `int` type
- the left operand **is convertible to** a numeric type, by unboxing to `int`
- therefore `==` is a numerical equality operation

---

### Summary

- If both operands of `==` and `!=` are reference types, it will always be a reference equality operation

  - It doesn't matter if the operands are convertible to numeric types
- If at least one of the operand is a numeric type, it will always be a numerical equality operation

  - Auto-unboxing on one (at most!) of the operands will be performed if necessary

#### References

- [JLS 4.2. Primitive Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2)

  - "The *numeric types* are the integral types and the floating-point types."
- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [JLS 5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8)
- [JLS 15.21.1 Numerical Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.1)
- [JLS 15.21.3 Reference Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.21.3)
- [JLS 5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6.2)

#### Related questions

- [When comparing two `Integers` in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)
- [Why are these `==` but not `equals()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259693/why-are-these-but-not-equals)
- [Java: What’s the difference between autoboxing and casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501653/java-whats-the-difference-between-autoboxing-and-casting)