# Comparing primitive to wrapper object with == behaviour unexplained

Tags: java, equals, equality, boxing

I have a piece of code which I need to understand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Character c = new Character('a');
    Character cy = new Character('a');
    char cx = 'a';

    System.out.println(c == cx);
    System.out.println(cx == cy);
    System.out.println(c == cy);
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

I am unable to understand why only the third statement is failing.

EDIT: This question is different to the `.equals` vs `==` question as this about primitive versus object comparison.

Comment: not quite, char primitive to object matching is working whereas the object to object matching is not...so i wondered why

Comment: Why is `new Object() == new Object()` false?

Comment: "This question is different to the .equals vs == question as this about primitive versus object comparison." No, it really isn't, since understanding that difference naturally explains this one. `==` does reference comparison; once you recognize that, the answer is trivial.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831945/is-it-guaranteed-that-new-integeri-i-in-java

Comment: @jpmc26 Except that that's wrong. `c` is a reference but `c == cx` doesn't do a reference comparison. The question is not the same.

Comment: @Boann The question is why `c == cy` returns `false`, not why `c == cx` returns `true`. Granted the OP may be confused on the latter point, but that could have been researched or asked if they applied the knowledge about reference comparison to `c == cy`, instead of wrongly assuming that the other comparisons implied it should be `true`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`c` and `cy` refer to different instances of the `Character` class (each time you invoke a constructor, you create a new instance), so comparing these references returns `false`.

On the other hand, when you compare either of them to the primitive `cx`, they are unboxed to `char`, and the `char` comparison returns true.

Had you used `Character.valueOf('a')` instead of `new Character('a')`, you would have gotten the same instance in both calls, and the reference comparison would have returned `true` (since `valueOf` returns a cached `Character` instance if the argument <= 127).

Comment: This part of Java is very confusing (not only) for beginners unfortunately. Since Java 5 there is autoboxing, which tries to be helpful but makes the behaviour of `==` even for tricky. Before autoboxing, I believe the compiler would have rejected the first two comparisons.

Comment: Note that `Character a = Character.valueOf('a')` can be shortened to `Character a = 'a'` and that even `valueOf` will return instances that are not equal for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Good IDEs can be configured to give a warning when boxing and unboxing will occur, as it does here.

Comment: @Thilo I don't see any auto-boxing the question, only auto-*un*boxing.

Answer (score 25):

```
 System.out.println(c == cx);
 System.out.println(cx == cy);
```

Since one is primitive and another is a wrapper class of it, [unboxing happens](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) and primitive comparison takes place (==).

Whereas:

```
 System.out.println(c == cy);
```

is an Object comparison. Different instances are getting compared so `==` won't work in this case.

Answer (score -1):

[Charcter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character) class is not singleton, so always a new object will be creating when calling the contructor and new objects refer to their respective references.So
`(c == cy)` gives you false

Comment: why do the other two comparisons give us true, then?

Comment: @Thilo for other comparison(involving primitive) boxing and autoboxing will happen

Comment: Even for Singletons each invocation of the constructor creates a new instance. It's just that invoking the constructor is made harder.

Comment: @Hulk In singleton constructor is called once

Comment: Yes, that is what the pattern is trying to achieve. Still, their constructor is not special in any way (except that it has the private-modifier), and *if* you invoke the constructor a second time, you get a separate instance.

Comment: @Hulk the only way would be using reflection... and that's off-topic

Comment: @SparK as is Singleton - it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -2):

it's obvious why the last comparision gives `false`: both `Character`s are explicitly initialized with `new`, thus being different objects

why the first two comparisions give `true`, however, is only partly clear: the `char` value is definitely used to retrieve a pre-stored `Character` instance, but I don't know how exactly the pre-defined `Character` objects are mapped to this pre-stored instance

I would expect, though, it works like "=="-comparision for `String` objects: if at compile time one of the compared instances is a pre-stored `Character` then the compiler inserts a call to `equals()` replacing the "=="-comparision

Comment: It's the opposite (as others have already correctly explained): [15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1): `If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2). Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).` So what's happening is unboxing, not boxing.

Comment: The char value is not at all ("definitely") used to retrieve a Character instance - instead the other side of the `==` is converted to a primitive character. And the compiler never replaces `==` with equals. Not for String objects, not for Character objects, not for any type of object.

Comment: But how come then that for Strings, `==` behaves just like `equals()`? It can't be array unboxing, that would do ref compare again, and from all I know operators can't be carried over as natives...