# NullPointerException using Long after equality check

Tags: java, casting, nullpointerexception, long-integer

This threw me.

If you have a Java Long variable and you check equality against a primitive value using the == operator the runtime type of the value is changed to a primitive long.

Subsequent checking the variable for a null value then throws an unexpected NullPointerException.

So in the test class:

```
public class LongDebug {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long validValue = 1L; 
    Long invalidValue = -1L;
    Long nullValue = null;

    System.out.println("\nTesting the valid value:");
    testExpectedBehaviour(validValue);
    testUnExpectedBehaviour(validValue);

    System.out.println("\nTesting the invalid value:");
    testExpectedBehaviour(invalidValue);
    testUnExpectedBehaviour(invalidValue);

    System.out.println("\nTesting the null value:");
    testExpectedBehaviour(nullValue);
    testUnExpectedBehaviour(nullValue);
}

/**
 * @param validValue
 */
private static void testExpectedBehaviour(Long value) {
    if (value == null || value == -1) System.out.println("Expected: The value was null or invalid");
    else System.out.println("Expected: The value was valid");
}

private static void testUnExpectedBehaviour(Long value) {
    try {
        if (value == -1 || value == null) System.out.println("Unexpected: The value was null or invalid");
        else System.out.println("Unexpected: The value was valid");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected: The system threw an unexpected NullPointerException");
    }
}
}
```

The result I get is:

```
Testing the valid value:
Expected: The value was valid
Unexpected: The value was valid

Testing the invalid value:
Expected: The value was null or invalid
Unexpected: The value was null or invalid

Testing the null value:
Expected: The value was null or invalid
Unexpected: The system threw an unexpected NullPointerException
```

Is this on spec or a bug in the JDK?

Comment: But the logician in me is upset. A || B ought to equal B || A.

Comment: Related: [Why comparing Integer with int can throw NullPointerException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352791)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
value == -1 || value == null
```

Expressions are evaluated from left to right and since `Long` must be unboxed first, JVM translates this to:

```
value.longValue() == -1 || value == null
```

And [`value.longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue%28%29) throws `NullPointerException` when `value` is `null` argument. It never reaches the second part of the expression.

It works when the order is different though:

```
value == null || value == -1
```

because if the `value` is `null`, the second part (that can cause `NullPointerException` when `value` is `null`) is never executed due to boolean expression [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

> Is this on spec or a bug in the JDK?

Of course this is not a bug. The way primitive value wrappers are unboxed is on spec ([*5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)):

> - If `r` is a reference of type `Long`, then unboxing conversion converts `r` into `r.longValue()`

After unboxing is applied, the rest is standard Java.

Comment: `valueOf(long)` auto-boxes. I think you mean `value.longValue()` to unbox the value.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this on spec or a bug in the JDK?

This is normal.  If you dereference a reference which is `null` you should get a NullPointerException. This means if you are going to check for `null` you have to check it before this happens.  Checking it after is pointless and confusing.

```
if (value == -1 || value == null)
```

is the same as

```
if (value.longValue() == -1 || value == null)
```

and the first part of the expression throws an NPE before the second part is run. If the first part doesn't fail the second part must be false.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the spec, specifically [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) and
[5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). The relevant parts:

> 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> [...]
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> [...]
>
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)

And:

> 5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion
>
> [...]
>
> - If r is a reference of type Long, then unboxing conversion converts r
>     into r.longValue()
>
> [...]
>
> - If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException

---

Note that `if (value == null || value == -1)` doesn't throw the exception because of *short-circuit evaluation*. Since `value == null` is `true`, the second part of the expression `value == -1` is never evaluated, so `value` is not unboxed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the order of the checks for null/primitive value in your two tests. Since you're passing null, this:

```
if (value == null || value == -1)
```

won't unbox, since the first check is true. The tests are performed left-to-right. This

```
if (value == -1 || value == null)
```

will try to unbox (to compare to -1), however, and fail since you're unboxing a `null` value. That behaviour (unboxing a null value throwing an exception) is expected.