# Want to know the internal code inferred by the compiler while unboxing

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, unboxing

**Code:-**

```
Integer value =null;
int a = value;
```

**Output:-**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I understand that unboxing failed because there is not int value for null reference.But can anyone tell me the method invoked which lead to nullPointerException

Comment: Because the runtime was trying to invoke `value.intValue()` internally to get the result, but `value` is `null`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @ZouZou you can use my comment as your answer.

Comment: Doesn't the log tell you where it happened?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's yours, not mine =)

Comment: Probably we should firstly check if it is duplicate.

Comment: @ferrerverck a quick search on a SEO leds me to this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3352791/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza not *exact* dup, but *very* similar

Comment: @Cruncher didn't say it is a dup, but also covers what OP asked.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know, just weighing in as it was a reply to somebody asking to check if it was a dup

Comment: You could just look at the stack trace...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, the log actually doesn't tell. However, by the time when i answer i didn't see `Luiggi Mendoza`'s comment. Otherwise i wouldn't try to dig up the JLS specification and answer it. But down voting this question is not completely understood by me

Comment: At first glance it doesn't seem like a good question, but it's subtler than it appears and is by no means obvious (and doesn't deserve the downvotes). I edited the title to be more descriptive of the problem and to hopefully be more searchable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While assigning the reference type `Integer` to corresponding primitive type `int` Unboxing  conversion happens. It is defined in [**jls-5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> If r is a reference of type Integer, then unboxing conversion converts
>   r into r.intValue()

So, when you are trying to unboxing it, the `value.intValue()` gets called resulting in NPE, as `value` is `null`

Answer (score 2):

You first have to understand that the code you have is actually compiled to something a little different.

```
[s_delima@ml-l-sotiriosd bin]$ /usr/java/latest/bin/javap -c Test.class 
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  ...   

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.io.IOException;
    Code:
       0: aconst_null   
       1: astore_1      
       2: aload_1       
       3: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
       6: istore_2      
       7: return        
}
```

You will notice that there is an invocation of `java/lang/Integer.intValue()`. Since your `Integer` variable is referencing `null`, you will get a `NullPointerException` when the invocation tries to dereference it.