# Is Java's equality operator commutative?

Tags: java, syntactic-sugar, autoboxing

Consider the following Java code:

```
Integer foo = bar();
if(foo == 5) ...;
if(5 == foo) ...;
```

Are these comparisons equal -- particularly in the possibility of `foo` being `null`? Do they expand to `foo.getValue() == 5` and `5 == foo.getValue()`, or to something more akin to `foo.equals(new Integer(5))` and `new Integer(5).equals(foo)`, or to something else? May one or the other or both or none throw an NPE?

Comment: It looks like you're asking whether it is symmetric, not commutative. Normal rules apply when it comes to what throws a NPE (though for what it's worth, I'm pretty sure most implementations return `false` if the argument is `null`.)

Comment: @user2864740: The question is not the same, as I'm also asking of the order of the operands matter.

Comment: @Dolda2000 That is why I merely linked it. Anyway, [*see the answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3352798/2864740) therein - it contains much information.

Comment: @user2864740: Ah, I see; sorry. I thought you were just pointing out a duplicate question.

Comment: @DennisMeng: No, this is what an operator being commutative means. I'm fairly sure that an operator `*` being "symmetric" means that `x*x` holds true, but I may remember that wrong.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur

Comment: @Dolda2000 Yep, you're remembering it wrong. `x*x` holding true would make it *reflexive*.

Comment: @DennisMeng: No, that is with regards to relations; operators use different terminology. Recall how matrix multiplication is commonly used as an example for something that is not commutative.

Comment: Ah wait, yes you're right. Guess I need more caffeine. :)

Comment: The order of operands does not matter for `==`. Whether it matters for `.equals()` is up to the implementation of `.equals()`, but best practice would say that `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> 15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or
>   one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to
>   numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands
>   (§5.6.2).

And the relevant rule from 5.1.8 is:

> If r is a reference of type Integer, then unboxing conversion converts
>   r into r.intValue()

And 5.6.2 says:

> 5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
>   conversion (§5.1.8).

Which means that `if(foo == 5) ...;` means the same as `if(foo.intValue() == 5) ...;` and `if(5 == foo)` means `if (5 == foo.intValue())`.
If `foo` equals `null` then you will get an NPE in either case.

Comment: Thanks! The quotes from the specification make it quite clear what is happening.

Comment: It's also worth noting that since Integer is final you can't do something crazy like overriding intValue() to be stateful. :)

Answer (score 1):

`==` is **symmetric**; that is to say, for any values `x` and `y`, `(x == y) == (y == x)`.  This is a guarantee provided to us by the JLS [§15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) for numbers, and [§15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) for reference types (or everything that isn't a primitive value).

It could also be seen as **transitive**, in that if three values `x, y, z` exist, and `x == y && y == z`, then `x == z`.  This is again provided by the same JLS  specification - merely repeated to mitigate the issue of the common variable `y`.

The **real** problem here comes with regards to autoboxing; when you go to unbox `null`, then [by the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8), you're going to get a `NullPointerException` - independent of the comparison operation you're going to do next.

Effectively:

- You have a boxed primitive type on one side of the comparison, and a primitive on the other.  The value of either isn't yet considered.
- Given that the value of the primitive [will force numerical comparison](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) due to it being a boxed primitive, Java will then try to unbox the boxed value.
- You can't unbox `null`, hence `NullPointerException`.

This is (kind of) where [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) steps in - by its contract, two non-null instances must be equivalent to each other if they are indeed the same thing.  If either (but not both) of these values are `null`, then they're not the same instances.

I say "kind of" since there's really nothing to enforce the supposed contract on `Object#equals`; you could (with some effort) write an asymmetric `equals()` method, although one would wonder why you would want to.

Comment: That second property is transitivity, not commutativity.

Comment: Actually, *symmetric* is the term used with regards to binary relations, while *commutative* is the term for binary operations. `==` can of course be considered as either, but I considered it primarily as an operation in this case (I thought it reasonable considering I was primarily interested in its side effects, rather than as a relation).

Comment: @Dolda2000: Side effects?  What side effects?  What's outlined by the JLS is merely how it behaves, each time - I couldn't imagine `==` having any side effects on the operands it receives.

Comment: @Makoto: It has the side effect of potentially throwing an exception, which is not definable for a relation.

Comment: That's not due to `==`; that's due to the unboxing of `null`, which is very well defined, and most definitely **not** a side effect.

Comment: But the unboxing of `null` is an implicit part of the `==` syntax. And the term "side effect" does not necessarily only carry the meaning it has with regards to functional programming languages. In this case, I use it as having an effect outside of the obvious effect of simply making a boolean comparison.

Comment: No...unboxing `null` doesn't *just* occur here.  It occurs when you need to do anything related to using that boxed instance, including assigning to a primitive value, or perform method operations on it (like `intValue()`).  Lastly, the *only* way it can make a boolean comparison is clearly defined in §15.21.1, which states that this comparison may perform unboxing conversions.  It's ***not*** a side effect.  It's very much intentional.  There's **no way** you can do a comparison between a wrapper and a primitive without unboxing the value in the wrapper class.

Comment: You are using a stricter definition of "side effect" than it necessarily has. And I never said that unboxing "only" occurs in this case; I merely said that it *does* occur here. And the unboxing can be considered a "side effect" because it is outside the obviously "main" effect of doing an equality comparison *per se*. The terms have meaning outside of Java. But I digress. We can take this to english.stackexchange.com if you wish. ;)

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no difference between 1 and 2

2) Compiler transforms `foo == 5` to `foo.intValue() == 5`  (outboxing)

3) If `foo` is `null` NPE is thrown at runtime