# java.lang.NullPointerException with boolean

Tags: java, methods

I wrote a realy simple code based on another question and here it is:

It throws me an error

> java.lang.NullPointerException line 5 and 17

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
 public class Main {

    public static String bool(Boolean param){
        if(param == true){    (line 5)
            return "a";
        }else if(param == false){
            return "b";
        }
        return "c";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(bool(true));
        System.out.println(bool(null)); (line 17)
        System.out.println(bool(false));


    }
}
```

Comment: One reason to avoid using Boolean (or other wrapper class types) if at all possible, or if you must use it, test it for null before using it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is our friend from a few minutes ago, testing out the solution to his assignment question :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: indeed. 1+ to your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why comparing Integer with int can throw NullPointerException in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-comparing-integer-with-int-can-throw-nullpointerexception-in-java)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`null` cannot be auto-unboxed to a primitive `boolean` value, which is what happens when you try to compare it with `true`. In

```
param == true
```

The type of `true` is `boolean`, therefore the left-hand operand must also be a `boolean`. You are passing in a `Boolean`, which is an object, but can be auto-unboxed to `boolean`.

Therefore this is equivalent to

```
param.booleanValue() == true
```

Clearly, if `param` is `null`, the above throws `NullPointerException`.

To avoid the hidden pitfalls of auto-unboxing, you could instead work with the `Boolean` objects:

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(param))
  return "a";
if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(param))
  return "b";
return "c";
```

Comment: Great trick with the Boolean statics and methods, it simplifies code so much! +1

Comment: This also works: 

`import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

if (param == TRUE) {} `

Comment: @sorin7486 It doesn't work in general: `new Boolean(true) != Boolean.TRUE`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are correct.. have I mentioned I don't like java? :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code compares a `java.lang.Boolean` instance with a primitive `boolean`, which means unboxing the `java.lang.Boolean`. Since `null` can't be unboxed, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

You could work around this by using the built in constants `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`:

```
public static String bool(Boolean param) {
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(param)) {
        return "a";
    } else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(param)) {
        return "b";
    }
    return "c";
}
```

Comment: Great trick with the Boolean statics and methods, it simplifies code so much! +1

Answer (score 0):

You used the `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. `Boolean` is a class, which means you can assign objects to it. In your case, you passed in a `null`, which is then assigned to param. You then tried to use param, which of course resulted in a `NullPointerException`.

You can:

- Get rid of the line `bool(null)`
- Change `Boolean` to `boolean` in the parameters for `bool()`
- Add an else if for when `param` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

So your program must be something like this.

```
public class BooleanBug {

    public static String bool(Boolean param) {
        if ((null != param) && param.booleanValue() == true) {
            return "a";
        } else if ((null != param) && param.booleanValue() == false) {
            return "b";
        }
        return "c";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(bool(true));
        System.out.println(bool(null));
        System.out.println(bool(false));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, as mentioned by others if param is null, the below throws NullPointerException.

```
param == true
```

According to the Java language specification, unboxing happens via calling **Boolean.booleanValue(), Number.longValue(), Number.intValue()** etc.
Its like calling those methods manually and NullPointerException is the result of unboxing a null.

We can also detect these Unboxing vulnerabilities, if not handled properly using static code analysis tools.
Kindly refer this for more information [Boolean Violation](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5411)