# Throwing NullPointerException for CodeWar question (Counting sheep)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am doing a question in CodeWar and I had encountered a few problems. The question basically accepts a Boolean array to count the number of sheep (true = add 1 to sumOfSheep, false does not add 1 to sum). This is the input and my code.

```
Boolean[] array1 = {true,  true,  true,  false,
                  true,  true,  true,  true ,
                  true,  false, true,  false,
                  true,  false, false, true ,
                  true,  true,  true,  true ,
                  false, false, true,  null };


public class Counter {
  public int countSheeps(Boolean[] arrayOfSheeps) {
    int sumOfSheep = 0;
    for(Boolean sheep:arrayOfSheeps){
      if(sheep){
        sumOfSheep++;
      }
      else if(sheep == null){
        continue;
      }
    }
    return sumOfSheep;
  }
}
```

After running this code, it will return a NullPointerException. I have tried to print out every element in the array and I noticed that it will crash when it encounters a null value.

```
if(sheep){
        sum++;
        System.out.print(sheep);
        System.out.println(" Good");
      }
      else if(sheep == null){
        System.out.println("Bad");
        continue;
      }
```

The program won't crash if I change the if statement's condition to `if(sheep != null && sheep)`. Can I know why is this happening??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NullPointerException with boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824269/java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-boolean)

Comment: Because you array is `Boolean[]`, not `boolean[]`. This allows for null values. If you evaluate an element of that array, auto-unboxing is performed. That turns a Boolean into a primitive `boolean` using `var.booleanValue()`. If `var` is `null`, a NPE is thrown.

Comment: Okay thank you!!
Then can I ask why `sheep == null` will crash and `sheep != null` won't crash??

Comment: @616Hz_lim neither `sheep == null` nor `sheep != null` will cause any NullPointerException. Both are fine. The Problem is when Java tries to convert your `Boolean` to a `boolean` which cannot be done for `null`. In case of `if(sheep != null && sheep)` it will only ever try to even evaluate the part after `&&` if the first `sheep != null` passes as `true` because of [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the indicated line, not in the `else if`:

```
  if (sheep) {                 // <-- FAILS if sheep == null
    sumOfSheep++; 
  } else if(sheep != null){    // <-- always safe, as is !(sheep == null)
    continue;
  }
```

The problem is that, if `sheep` is a `Boolean` (and thus a reference to an object), trying to *convert* it to `true` or `false` (by looking at whether it is pointing to `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`) will, when it is actually pointing to `null`, throw `NullPointerException`. You need to *compare* it against `Boolean.TRUE` instead:

```
  if (sheep == Boolean.TRUE){ // Boolean.TRUE == sheep would have also worked
    sumOfSheep++;
  }
```

Comparing *object references* with `==` is always fine, regardless of whether some are null, because no conversion will be attempted. Trying to convert a null reference to a boolean (or any non-reference), on the other hand, fails as it should.