# Initializing a general HashMap with constant values for a class

Tags: java, enums, maps, constants

I am having problems instantiating a general HashMap with constant values. I intend to track inventory of various car types in a car rental service; with car type serving as key and num available to rent as the value.
I attempted using a method createAvailable cars which initializes the map to constants for max number of each car type. For further testing I included a setMaxCarsAvailable method as well. Despite all this I get a NullPointer Exception coming from my canReserveVehicle method [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOtSp.png)on the line specifying that if there are 0 available cars then you can't reserve a vehicle. How do I properly handle inventory with my map of cars? Where should I place it? I tried using a static method and later including it in a constructor with no luck. See my code below.. (I have included a picture of the stack trace showing the errors in the testCase class. I hope all this extra info helps)

```
public class CarReservationController {
String phoneNumber; 
long numDays = 0; 
Vehicle vehicle;
VehicleType vType;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

public static final int MAX_ECONOMY = 10; //used this to track the amount of cars available to rent. This was applied in the canReserveVehicle and addReservation methods
public static final int MAX_PREMIUM = 10; 
public static final int MAX_SUV = 5;

public CarReservationController()
{
    availableCars = createAvailableCarsMap(); //this is my attempt at instantiating my availableCars map to contain (VehicleType.ECONOMY, 10), (VehicleType.PREMIUM, 10), map.put(VehicleType.SUV, 5); ;
}

Map<VehicleType, Integer> availableCars; 
Map<VehicleType, PriorityQueue<Date>> reservedVehicleReturnDates = new HashMap<>(); // Map from vehicle type to reserved car end dates. This will hold all the current reservations end dates for each vehicle type
//was public static map
public HashMap<String, List<CarReservation>> reservationsMap = new HashMap<>();
//previously private static Map... 
private Map<VehicleType, Integer> createAvailableCarsMap() {
    Map<VehicleType, Integer> map = new EnumMap<VehicleType, Integer>(VehicleType.class);
    map.put(VehicleType.ECONOMY, MAX_ECONOMY);
    map.put(VehicleType.PREMIUM, MAX_PREMIUM);
    map.put(VehicleType.SUV, MAX_SUV);
    return map;
}



public void setMaxCarsAvailable(VehicleType v, int maxAvailable) {
        availableCars.put(v, maxAvailable);
}

//I UPDATE carReservationsMap here..this adds an actual reservation but first it checks the boolean canReserveVehicle below
public void addReservation(CarReservation res) throws Exception //right here
{   

    Date sDate = res.getStartDate(); //HERE
    Date eDate = res.getEndDate(); //HERE
    String phoneNumber = res.getPhoneNumber();
        if(canReserveVehicle(vType, phoneNumber, sDate, eDate)) {
            if (reservationsMap.containsKey(phoneNumber)) {
                List<CarReservation> currCustomerRes = reservationsMap.get(phoneNumber);
                currCustomerRes.add(res);
                reservationsMap.put(phoneNumber, currCustomerRes);
            } else {
                List<CarReservation> currCustomerRes = new ArrayList<CarReservation>(Arrays.asList(res));
                reservationsMap.put(phoneNumber, currCustomerRes);
            }
            int countForVehicleType = availableCars.get(vType);
            availableCars.put(vType, countForVehicleType - 1);
            if (reservedVehicleReturnDates.containsKey(vType)) {
                reservedVehicleReturnDates.get(vType).add(eDate);
            } else {
                PriorityQueue<Date> q = new PriorityQueue<Date>();
                reservedVehicleReturnDates.put(vType, q);
            }
        }   
}

//NULL POINTER EXCEPTION COMING UP HERE FROM JUNIT TESTS
public boolean canReserveVehicle(VehicleType v, String phoneNumber, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws ParseException 
{
    PriorityQueue<Date> reservedVehicleQueue = reservedVehicleReturnDates.get(v);
    if(endDate.before(startDate))
        return false; // check that the start date of the reservation is before the end date 

    if (availableCars.get(v) == 0) { /// SAYS THERE IS A NULL POINTER EXCEPTION from here... because availableCars is still 0..
        Date nextCarReturnDate = reservedVehicleQueue.peek();
        if(nextCarReturnDate.after(startDate))
            return false; // return false if a reserved car is not going to be available before the new customer is requesting one.
    }
    else {
        // If a car that will become available before the customer requests it, remove it from the queue and replace with the 
        //requesting customer's return date (as they now lay claim to the car)
        reservedVehicleQueue.poll();
        reservedVehicleQueue.add(endDate);
    }

    //these are comparing strings.
    if (reservationsMap.containsKey(phoneNumber)) {
        List<CarReservation> resByCustomer = reservationsMap.get(phoneNumber);
        CarReservation lastResByCustomer = resByCustomer.get(resByCustomer.size() - 1); 
        Date lastResEndDate = sdf.parse(lastResByCustomer.endDate);
        if (startDate.before(lastResEndDate)) {  //1 customer can only have one rental at a time within the system.
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;    
}
```

}

Test case looks like this with "java.lang.NullPointerException" CarReservationController.canReserveCarVehicle"

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CarReservationTest {

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 


@Test
public void testThatCustomerCanMakeReservation() throws Exception {
    CarReservationController reservationSystem = new CarReservationController();
    reservationSystem.setMaxCarsAvailable(VehicleType.PREMIUM, 2);
    CarReservation firstRes = new CarReservation(VehicleType.PREMIUM, "Jon Snow", "1234567890", "2019-01-23", "2019-01-31");
    reservationSystem.addReservation(firstRes);
    //assertTrue(reservationSystem.reservationsMap.containsKey("1234567890"));
    assertTrue(reservationSystem.reservationsMap.size() > 0);
    assertEquals(firstRes, reservationSystem.reservationsMap.get("1234567890"));
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding values to `reservationsMap`?

Comment: Please provide full exception stack trance, from where you are calling `canReserveVehicle`? Also don't write stack trace manually please copy paste it so you don't have typo.

Comment: Hi @Janik I included the image of the stack trace as well as the addReservation method which gives more context to the canReserveVehicle

Comment: @nabster that happens in the addReservation method which I have included in the edit. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @Andy Turner why is it getting marked as duplicate when it is not helping the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that make this complicated to debug.

Perhaps most important for the question you asked, without a full stacktrace, it isn't obvious whether the NPE you are seeing is from `availbleCars.get(v)` or from `availableCars.get(v) == 0`.

That issue is complicated by the fact that without knowing what the `ReservationSystem::addReservation` method does, I don't think it's possible to rule out either possibility.

**Possibility 1**

However, if the issue is from `availableCars.get(v) == 0`, then it might be from your choice to compare equality between an `Integer` and a numeric primitive using `==` instead of `.equals()`. Please see this previous answer for a more complete discussion: [Why comparing Integer with int can throw NullPointerException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-comparing-integer-with-int-can-throw-nullpointerexception-in-java)

**Possibility 2**

If the issue is from `availableCars.get(v)` (that `availableCars` itself is `null`), then you may have an issue with how you are instantiating that `availableCars` map. The method you are using there doesn't need to be static, and also you don't need the setter you have created.

**Next Steps**

To solve this problem, I'd recommend using a breakpoint or breaking that comparison into two steps with debug statements - first check to see that `availableCars` is not null, then check that `availableCars.get(v)` is an `Integer`, and then use `.equals()` to check the equality with `0`.

In addition, you might try unit testing your methods to instantiate the `availableCars` map and the `ReservationSystem::addReservation` method separately as well, to help narrow down where the bug might be.

Comment: Good catch with  Integer countForVehicleType = availableCars.get(vType);I changed that to int instead. I removed the static keyword from createAvailableCarsMap() too but still getting NullPointerException. stemming fromavailableCars.get(v) == 0. I guess this comes back to my original question, how do I properly populate my availableCarsMap.. Enlighten me on the proper syntax.