# the difference of "==" and "equals“ in Java

Tags: java, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these == but not `equals()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259693/why-are-these-but-not-equals)

I know in Java, "==" is used to compared reference  not values while "equals" to is used to compare values.

Then if

```
int a=100;
int b=100;
boolean c=(a==b);
```

Then c will be false? But I remember in my previous project, it seems to be true....

Comment: equals compare references when you have objects.

Comment: The most common mistake is to use == for Strings, which is not correct because String is not a primitive type. (All datatypes that by default have boldtext in Eclipse is primitive)

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg  I see. So Strings and other kind of classes are not primitive. Types like int are primitive:>

Comment: int, double, float, boolean... and more are primitive. Primitive types are not classes. See the answer by Jake King for more information on which data types are primitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

c is true, because you're comparing primitives, not references. == compares primitives by value (since the value is all you've got).

Comment: technically, == compares objects by value too.  it just so happens that an object's value is memory location (ie. reference).  Hence why java is also always pass by value (and never pass by reference).

Comment: @Matt: agreed, the references are passed by value.

Answer (score 3):

Using `==` works on all [primitive data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to compare values, since primitives do not contain references. Objects contain object references instead, so using `==` compares those instead.

The int value of 100 *does* equal 100, so `c` will be true.

Comment: +1 for the link reference explaining primitive data types!

Answer (score 1):

c will be `true` because `a` and `b` are primitives and their values are same.

Answer (score 1):

`Integers` are `value types`. So in this case it just compares the values, so `c` will be `true`.